# how can i use message with parameter using spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to externalize application message to properties file. I'm loading the properties file using Spring.

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <property name="locations">
  <list>      
     <value>classpath:applicationmessage.properties</value>      
  </list>
 </property>
 <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
```

I have the message with para

```
message.myMessage = Couldn't find resource for customer id {0} and business unit {1}
```

What's the best way to read this message with parameter from java file ? Is there any other approach to externalize the messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi there are several ways to get properties message from spring.

way 1:

```
<util:properties id="Properties" location="classpath:config/taobaoConfig.properties" />
```

add this in spring.xml

in your java file . you create following property.

```
 @Resource(name = "Properties")
private Properties serverProperties;
```

the key-value in properties file  will in serverProperties property.

way 2:

create a properties  container bean

```
<bean id="propertyUtil" class="com.PropertiesUtil">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/datasource.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/fileDef.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

code of com.PropertiesUtil

```
    public class PropertiesUtil extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {
private Properties properties;

@Override
protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Properties props) {
    super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);
    this.properties = props;
}

/**
 * Get property from properties file.
 * @param name property name
 * @return property value
 */
public String getProperty(final String name) {
    return properties.getProperty(name);
}
}
```

you can use this container bean to get key-value in properties files .

Comment: How do manage the placeholder which part of the message. I'm mainly looking solution for that.

Answer (score 4):

It depends, exists differents ways to do, directly in jsp, in form validation process, etc..

For example

Message in properties:

```
msg=My message {0} and {1}.
```

In your jsp:

```
<spring:message code="msg" 
                arguments="${value1},${value2}" 
                htmlEscape="false"/>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.message